# How to save spinner state on device rotation using a ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner, viewmodel, android-spinner

How do you restore the Spinners selected item index a view model?

Right now I have a setup where you set a `selectedIndex` property on the `ViewModel` within the spinners `OnItemSelectedListener`.

The problem I'm running into is that every time the Fragment recreates, the selected listener gets re-assigned to the spinner, and the `OnItemSelectedListener` get fired for index 0, overriding whatever is stored in the `ViewModel`.

I feel like I'm missing something super simple here.

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        // Set the spinners onItemSelectedListener
        binding.spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                viewModel.setSelectedItem(p2)
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }

        // Restore spinner to previously selected state
        viewModel.getSelectedCompanyIndex().let {
            binding.spinner.setSelection(it)
        }

        // Observe the spinner data.
        viewModel.spinnerData.observe(this) { spinnerArray ->
            ArrayAdapter(
                requireContext(),
                R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                spinnerArray
            ).also {
                binding.spinner.adapter = it
            }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting viewModel instance using viewModelProvider?

Comment: Did you try calling setSelection from viewmodel data _before_ adding selection listener?

Comment: @MidasLefko I have tried that and it doesn't work. For some reason the selection listener is getting called with an index of 0 AFTER everything else resetting the selection to the first item every time

Comment: @MuhammadZahab Yes I am!

Comment: @cabyambo android built in spinner is sometimes hard to work with (as you have experienced firsthand), I have found [this library](https://github.com/skydoves/PowerSpinner) much more user friendly.